# Jenkins ArtifactDeployer simple creates a new dir in base dir?

Tags: jenkins, archiva

I am in Jenkins and using ArtifactDeployer. The console output tells me that the remote repo is http:// myrepo but all it does is create a new folder in my base directory which I also specify in this plugin. It correctly finds only one file to copy but strangely just creates a new directory and copies it in there. I thought this would enable me to deploy artifacts to another server... Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not do that with artifacts deployer but there are other ones you can use - read below:

Jenkins provides by default a feature for archiving artifacts generated by the build of a Jenkins Job. These artifacts are archived in the JENKINS_HOME directory. However, this directory contains also tool configurations (global and job configurations). Therefore, there is no separation between infrastructure data, jobs data and generated elements. It is often considered to be a bad practice and it doesn't help to manage it from an administrator point of view.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to extend the 'archived artifacts' feature to archive artifacts in a location other than JENKINS_HOME.

The main goal of the ArtifactDeployer plugin is to archive artifacts in your desired locations (other than JENKINS_HOME directory).

There are many Jenkins plugins close to ArtifactDeployer such as **CopyArtifact plugin** or **CopyArchiver plugin** for publishing artifacts from Jenkins resources (from the current workspace, from the old builds of the same job or other jobs, ...) to remote locations with the protocol file://

There are also others plugins for managing other protocols such as ftp://, ssh:///.